# Yet another 9patch drawable question

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got relative layout in my view hierarchy and I want it to have this as background:
[image]

Here's xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          >
          <TextView
           <!-- -->
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          />
          <Spinner
           <!-- -->
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:minWidth="200dp"
          />
        </RelativeLayout>
        
        <!-- Nested Relative layouts as above go here -->
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's what I receive:

[image]
[image]

It seems that 9patch causes the problem, because I tried other drawables and my layout didn't behave like this. Could you point me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your padding doesn't seem right, the black part on right and bottom should be almost the entire width  / height (except rounded corners).
I think it is the result your are waiting for.

Comment: Exactly this. The bottom and right borders define the content area, the top and left define your stretch points. The rectangle defined by the intersection of the bottom and right border areas will determine the area Android uses to position your content.

Comment: Thanx, I was confused with all that drawable stuff, but now it's all clear.